# Show script on all pages except one

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, script

I have this MailChimp embed script (for a subscribe popup) that I want to use on all the pages in my Magento 1 installation, except for one CMS page (because it already contains an embed script for a subscribe popup).

Normally, I would add this script to the 'Miscellaneous Scripts' option in System > Configuration > Design. How can I solve this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the script using xml. Then you could use the **layout update xml** tab within the admin for the CMS page you want to remove script from the page. **e.g**:

> **1. Add JS to all pages**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
      <reference name="head">
        <action  method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/popup.js</name></action>
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

This could be added to your **local.xml** file within your theme and will apply to all pages then due to being within default node.

> **2. Remove JS from a CMS Page**:

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/popup.js</name>
  </action>
</reference>
```

This can be added to that CMS pages **layout update xml** field within admin so is just applied to that page. Navigate to CMS -> Pages -> Design. Then paste above into the **layout update xml** field.

> **3. Add JS file to filesystem.**

The **popup.js** file should then be placed within the themes's JS folder:

```
skin/frontend/theme/default/js/popup.js
```

Comment: Very nice answer! I had multiple javascript files, so I used your method, but instead of using js files, I used a static block. Still, good answer!